# Face Recognition using Opencv and JavaCV

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

```
   import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
   import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;
   import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
   import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.createLBPHFaceRecognizer;
   import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.cvHaarDetectObjects;

   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileInputStream;
   import java.util.Iterator;
   import java.util.Properties;
   import java.util.Set;
   import com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader;
   import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
   import com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber;
   import com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber;
   import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.FaceRecognizer;
   import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvMat;
   import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvMemStorage;
   import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvRect;
   import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.CvSeq;
   import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
   import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.MatVector;
   import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvLoadImage;
   import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect;
   import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING;
   import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.CvHaarClassifierCascade;
   import java.io.OutputStream;
   import java.io.FileOutputStream;
   import java.util.logging.Level;
   import java.util.logging.Logger;
   import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

public class LBPFaceRecognizer {
 private static String faceDataFolder = "F:\\FaceID\\ID\\";
    public  static String imageDataFolder = faceDataFolder + "images\\";
    private static final String CASCADE_FILE = "C:\\Users\\chatur\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\NetbeansWorkspace\\DemoFaceRecognize-master\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml";
 public   static final String personNameMappingFileName = faceDataFolder + "personNumberMap.properties";

    static final CvHaarClassifierCascade cascade = new CvHaarClassifierCascade(cvLoad(CASCADE_FILE));
    private static LBPFaceRecognizer instance = new LBPFaceRecognizer();
    Properties dataMap = new Properties();
    private static final int NUM_IMAGES_PER_PERSON =10;
    double binaryTreshold = 100;
    int highConfidenceLevel = 70;
    private FaceRecognizer fr_binary = null;
     private LBPFaceRecognizer() {
            if(cascade!=null)
            {System.out.println(cascade+"\t"+CASCADE_FILE);}
    createModels();
    loadTrainingData();
    }
     public  static LBPFaceRecognizer getInstance() {
            return instance;
    }
    private void createModels() {
            fr_binary = createLBPHFaceRecognizer(1, 8, 8, 8, binaryTreshold);
    }
    protected CvSeq detectFace(IplImage originalImage) {
        System.out.println("in detection");
        CvSeq faces = null;
        Loader.load(opencv_objdetect.class);
        try {
                    IplImage grayImage = IplImage.create(originalImage.width(), originalImage.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
                    cvCvtColor(originalImage, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
                    CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();
                    faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(grayImage, cascade, storage, 1.1,3,CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING);
                    for(int i=0;i<faces.total();i++){
                    CvRect r=new CvRect(cvGetSeqElem(faces,i));
                    cvRectangle(originalImage, cvPoint(r.x(),r.y()),cvPoint(r.x()+r.width(),r.y()+r.height()),CvScalar.YELLOW,1,CV_AA,0);;
                     }
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
      return faces;
    }
            public String identifyFace(IplImage image) {
            System.err.println("==========================================================");
            String personName = "";

            Set keys = dataMap.keySet();

            if (keys.size() > 0) {
                    int[] ids = new int[1];
                    double[] distance = new double[1];
                    int result = -1;

                            fr_binary.predict(image, ids, distance);
                            //just deriving a confidence number against treshold
                            result = ids[0];

                            if (result > -1 && distance[0]<highConfidenceLevel) {
                                    personName = (String) dataMap.get("" + result);
                            }
            }

            return personName;
    }
        public boolean learnNewFace(String personName, IplImage[] images) throws Exception
         {
             System.out.println("in learn new face");
            int memberCounter = dataMap.size();
            System.out.println(memberCounter);
            if(dataMap.containsValue(personName)){
                    Set keys = dataMap.keySet();
                    Iterator ite = keys.iterator();
                    while (ite.hasNext()) {
                            String personKeyForTraining = (String) ite.next();
                            String personNameForTraining = (String) dataMap.getProperty(personKeyForTraining);
                            if(personNameForTraining.equals(personName)){
                                    memberCounter = Integer.parseInt(personKeyForTraining);
                                    System.out.println(memberCounter);
                                    System.err.println("Person already exist.. re-learning..");
                            }
                    }
            }

            dataMap.put("" + memberCounter, personName);
            storeTrainingImages(personName, images);
            retrainAll();

            return true;
    }
    public IplImage preprocessImage(IplImage image, CvRect r){
            IplImage gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
            IplImage roi = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
            System.out.println("in preprocessing");
           CvRect r1 = new CvRect(r.x()-10, r.y()-10, r.width()+10, r.height()+10);
            cvCvtColor(image, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
            cvSetImageROI(gray, r1);
            cvResize(gray, roi, CV_INTER_LINEAR);
            cvEqualizeHist(roi, roi);
            return roi;

    }
    private void retrainAll() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("in retrainAll");
            Set keys = dataMap.keySet();

            if (keys.size() > 0) {
                    MatVector trainImages = new MatVector(keys.size() * NUM_IMAGES_PER_PERSON);
                    CvMat trainLabels = CvMat.create(keys.size() * NUM_IMAGES_PER_PERSON, 1, CV_32SC1);
                    Iterator ite = keys.iterator();
                    int count = 0;

                    System.err.print("Loading images for training...");
                    while (ite.hasNext()) {
                            String personKeyForTraining = (String) ite.next();
                            String personNameForTraining = (String) dataMap.getProperty(personKeyForTraining);
                            IplImage imagesForTraining[]=new IplImage[NUM_IMAGES_PER_PERSON];
                            imagesForTraining = readImages(personNameForTraining);
                            System.out.println("length\t"+imagesForTraining.length+"\t"+personNameForTraining);
                            IplImage grayImage[]=new IplImage[NUM_IMAGES_PER_PERSON];                    

                            for(int j=0;j<imagesForTraining.length;j++){         
                                    grayImage[j] = IplImage.create(imagesForTraining[j].width(), imagesForTraining[j].height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
                            }

                            for (int i = 0; i < imagesForTraining.length; i++) {
                                    trainLabels.put(count, 0, Integer.parseInt(personKeyForTraining));
                                    cvCvtColor(imagesForTraining[i], grayImage[i], CV_BGR2GRAY);
                                    trainImages.put(count,grayImage[i]);
                                    count++;
                            }
    }
                    System.err.println("done.");
                                            fr_binary.train(trainImages, trainLabels);
                    System.err.println("done.");
                    storeTrainingData();
            }
           }
        private void loadTrainingData() {

            try {

                    File personNameMapFile = new File(personNameMappingFileName);
                    if (personNameMapFile.exists()) {
                        System.out.print("in if ");
                            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(personNameMapFile);
                            dataMap.load(fis);
                            System.out.println("datdataMap"+dataMap);
                            fis.close();
                            dataMap.list(System.out);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
       private void storeTrainingData() throws Exception {
       System.err.print("Storing training models ....");
       File personNameMapFile = new File("personNameMappingFileName");
            if (personNameMapFile.exists()) {
                    personNameMapFile.delete();
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(personNameMapFile, false);
            dataMap.store(fos, "");
            fos.close();

            System.err.println("done.");
    }

        public void storeTrainingImages(String personName, IplImage[] images) {
           System.out.println("in store");
            for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                    String imageFileName = imageDataFolder + "training\\" + personName + "_" + i + ".bmp";
                    File imgFile = new File(imageFileName);
                    if (imgFile.exists()) {
                            imgFile.delete();
                    }
                    cvSaveImage(imageFileName, images[i]);
            }
                           System.out.println("exit store");

        }
        private IplImage[] readImages(String personName) {
            File imgFolder = new File(imageDataFolder);
            IplImage[] images = null;
            if (imgFolder.isDirectory() && imgFolder.exists()) {
                    images = new IplImage[NUM_IMAGES_PER_PERSON];
                    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_IMAGES_PER_PERSON; i++) {
                            String imageFileName = imageDataFolder + "training\\" + personName + "_" + i + ".bmp";
                            IplImage img = cvLoadImage(imageFileName);
                            images[i] = img;
                    }

            }
            return images;
         }
      public static void main(String ar[]) throws FrameGrabber.Exception, Exception{
     try{
        //LBPFaceRecognizer fr=new  LBPFaceRecognizer();
       //fr.getInstance();
       LBPFaceRecognizer fr = LBPFaceRecognizer.getInstance();

        FrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);
        grabber.start();
        IplImage img=null;

        CvSeq faces=null;
        CvRect r=null;
        CanvasFrame canvas=new CanvasFrame("webcam");
        canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        canvas.setSize(750,750);
        boolean flag=true;
        while(flag){
        img = grabber.grab();          
        IplImage snapshot = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), img.depth(), img.nChannels());
        cvFlip(img, snapshot, 1);         
        faces = fr.detectFace(img);
                    if(img!=null){
        canvas.showImage(img);
        }
        r=new CvRect(cvGetSeqElem(faces,0));
        int imageCounter = 0;
        IplImage trainImages[]= new IplImage[1];
        trainImages[0]= fr.preprocessImage(img, r);
        fr.learnNewFace("p", trainImages);
        fr.identifyFace(fr.preprocessImage(img, r));
        }
        }
        catch(ExceptionInInitializerError e)
         {
           System.out.println(e);
         }
         }
         }
```

The above code is for face recognition. It detects faces but while training it is throwing exception. the thing is it is throwing an exception called "java.lang.NullPointerException" in retrainAll() method.
at the statement

```
    grayImage[j] = IplImage.create(imagesForTraining[j].width(), imagesForTraining[j].height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
```

pls help to sort out this.

Comment: the first thing you can do is to split your line to see which is throwin the exception: grayImage[j] = IplImage.create(imagesForTraining[j].width(), imagesForTraining[j].height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

Comment: int width = imagesForTraining[j].width();

Comment: int height = imagesForTraining[j].height();

Comment: grayImage[j] = IplImage.create(width, height, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

Comment: and lets see the new exception line and we will solve it without reading the whole thing :)

Comment: it is resolved thank you sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IplImage img = cvLoadImage(imageFileName);
```

That thing can return null. So one of your `imagesForTraining[j]` is null.
That is causing the problem.

if you change your code to:

```
int width = imagesForTraining[j].width();   

int height = imagesForTraining[j].height();

grayImage[j] = IplImage.create(width, height, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
```

the exception will be thrown on the first of these 3 lines.
You should think about the scenario and where your image is not loaded and implement it. Simple implementation is something like:

```
if(imagesForTraining[j] == null)continue;//or do something, try to load again 
int width = imagesForTraining[j].width();   

int height = imagesForTraining[j].height();

grayImage[j] = IplImage.create(width, height, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
```

Comment: It is solved. The exception was at cvLoadImage() method resolved. but now at final method identifyFace() it is throwing an exception like

Comment: '  OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (rect.width >= 0 && rect.height >= 0 && rect.x < image->width && rect.y < image->height && rect.x + rect.width >= (int)(rect.width > 0) && rect.y + rect.height >= (int)(rect.height > 0)) in cvSetImageROI, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line 3006 '

Comment: better try your Debugger, you wont solve that thing if you really didnt know for the null pointer exception. But you should check the size of the image you are giving to that method and read the documentation of that third party api

Comment: while executing detection the accuracy is very less. it detects objects other than face also can you pls tell me how to remove this and impove accuracy

Comment: You should accept my answer with the tick next to it if it helped you

Comment: It's rude without that

Comment: Rohit, if this is happening I think you have implemented the case when it was null in the wrong way

Comment: paste your new code and I will take a look what is possibly wrong now

Comment: the code is same as the above I have not updated the code. I didn't got your comment that I have implemented the case when it was null in wrong way

Comment: because you had null pointer exception at the begining. dont you have it now without a change?

Comment: btw face recognition is one of the most difficult tasks in the IT sphere, so there will be problems for sure, especially as you have chosen a free solution without support

Comment: I have made changes in properties and exception has gone